# Why is php5.3.8 10 times slower than 5.3.7?

Tags: php

I just upgraded to php 5.3.8 using dotdeb.org's apt source.

The test result of php performance is very bad.

I test with this script, before and after install php5.3.8. It seems to run the same code will take 10 times time in php5.3.8 than in php5.3.7.

Test php script:

```
<?php
//test float
function test_float() {
    $t = pi();
    $timeStart = gettimeofday();

    for($i = 0; $i < 3000000; $i++) {
        sqrt($t);
    }

    $timeEnd = gettimeofday();
    $time = ($timeEnd["usec"]-$timeStart["usec"])/1000000+$timeEnd["sec"]-$timeStart["sec"];
    $time = round($time, 3)."s";
    return $time;
}

echo "php version:" , phpversion(), "\n";
echo "call sqrt()  3,000,000 times will cost ", test_float(), "\n";

?>
```

Test result:

```
php version:5.3.3-7+squeeze3
call sqrt()  3,000,000 times will cost 1.369s
php version:5.3.3-7+squeeze3
call sqrt()  3,000,000 times will cost 1.095s
php version:5.3.3-7+squeeze3
call sqrt()  3,000,000 times will cost 1.072s
php version:5.3.8-1~dotdeb.2
call sqrt()  3,000,000 times will cost 10.644s
php version:5.3.8-1~dotdeb.2
call sqrt()  3,000,000 times will cost 10.567s
php version:5.3.8-1~dotdeb.2
call sqrt()  3,000,000 times will cost 10.343s
```

Comment: How was the dotdeb version compiled? Given it's from a completely different source, you'r comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 5.3.8 version may have been compiled with debug options, or without compiler optimisations.

Or you may have added some slow extension in PHP 5.3.8 that's not enabled in PHP 5.3.7, like **xdebug** or **suhosin**.

I would bet for the second solution.

- Compare the output of `php -m`. (List of loaded modules.)
- Try running the benchmark with `php -n` (runs PHP without loading any ini settings file)

Comment: Thanks arnaud. It did cause by xdebug, when run with php -n, php 5.3.8 is just as fast as before. It seems that xdebug should keep up with  new release php.

Answer (score 2):

That does not matter anyway, as there is a [critical security bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55439) in 5.3.7. Function `crypt` returns only `salt`.  So, no matter slower it or faster, it's not recommended to use 5.3.7

Comment: Only matters if you use `crypt`. Believe me or not, not every application needs it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarks and performance analysis should always be done **on real code, the one you're trying to optimize the performance**.

In fact, maybe it's only the sqrt() function that is slower, and 99% of all the function 3 times faster. I think the problem comes from you benchmark.

Also, please check that you compiled php the same way on both version, on the same machine, same php.ini etc.